# How to set theme on first and second activities programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm create app with 2 activity and want set theme onclick button in first and second activity.

method setTheme() work only on first activity

```
    if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
        setTheme(R.style.OLEDTheme);
    } else {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }
    Switch oledModeSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.OLEDSwitch);
    if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
        oledModeSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }
    oledModeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean Check) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
            finish();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_alpha, R.anim.to_alpha);
            }
            startActivity(intent);
            if (Check) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Тема успешно активирована", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Тема успешно дезактивирована", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Theme set only first activity, but I expect set on first and second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setTheme()` it only changes the theme for the `Activity` that made the call. If you want to change the theme for your entire application, then you should record the theme setting in `SharedPreferences` and then in each `Activity` you should read the current theme from `SharedPreferences` and call `setTheme()` in that `Activity`.